# Logging user activities

Tags: linux, audit

I add the following line to my bash_profile file to log all my activities.

```
script ~/mylog_$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M').log
```

If I have 100 users, I can not modify all the user accounts with the change mentioned above. Is there any way Linux (centos) will do it automatically?
I tried the audit deamon :

```
/etc/init.d/auditd start 
/etc/init.d/psacct start
```

But none of it does what I can do by editing bash_profile file.

Comment: Do you want to log the activity for security reasons? What prevents the users from deleting their logs?

Comment: Flavor of linux?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: There are times when myself or colleagues need to go back and see what the command they typed and what the output was at that point of time. Not for security reason. The file can be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pam_tty_audit](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_tty_audit) PAM module logs *everything*, including individual key strokes. Is that too much detail for you? `aureport` can then generate human-readable reports for you, for example

```
aureport --tty -ts today
```

Answer (score 0):

use sudosh or ttyrec.
the command you gave would not work and will create lot of complications for you in future.
use the right tool at right place.

Also check : [Logging a "persons" activity in Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/268082/logging-a-persons-activity-in-linux)